# Eclipse Juno graphical bug?

Tags: eclipse

I've been looking on Google for a solution to this, but I don't even know which words should I use to find it...
Anyway, my problem is that Eclipse looks like this in Linux Mint 14 x64:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBfyg.png

I'm using Eclipse downloaded from their webpage, not from the repositories.
I've tried resetting the perspective, deleting both the eclipse and workspace folders but it keeps looking like this.
Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I finally managed to get rid of it. It looks like it had something to do with GTK. I changed the appearance to Classic in Preferences and it solved it.

Comment: what flavor of Linux are you on?

Comment: Linux Mint 14 x64 with Cinnamon

Comment: From this page of Eclipse Downloads which platform of linux did you choose? http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2.1-201209141800/ If you have downloaded else where, try downloading from here and let me know if it works

Comment: Already solved, explanation in question.

Comment: Didn't work for me.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to Window > Preferences > General > Appearance and changing the theme to Classic seems to solve the problem.

Comment: note that a full restart of eclipse is required to fully fix the issue

Comment: +1 Hanekoma and StrikeForceZero: thank you that solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

Changing the Eclipse Preferences from GTK to Classic did not work for me. Only the background of some Eclipse components get displayed in gray then which makes the visual corruptions less visible.

Yet it helped to change the GTK theme in Linux Mint from "Mint-X" to "Adwaita", which also looks ok. So this could be a workaround.

Update: This is a bit bug/issue/missing feature in the Mint-X theme which can easily be fixed manually. See http://dentrassi.de/2013/04/23/fixing-the-mint-x-theme-for-eclipseswt/