# Eclipse Luna Dark Theme - check not visible

Tags: eclipse, ide

Say, for example, you press Ctrl+F, and then you get to check on the white square for case sensitive or not. The check is too pale, it's almost invisible. Is there a fix for this?

My operating system is

```
Linux 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6
```

Comment: You didn't say what O/S, but there are bug reports on this problem for Linux. Did you search Google? And this question has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: No solution in Google.

Comment: It is a known bug. Hence the bug reports. I fight this problem every single day.: label issues, unreadable hyperlinks and task labels from Mylyn, strange task notifications, etc. You can try exporting `SWT_GTK3=0` to see if it helps you. One article [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482920/how-can-i-properly-configure-my-eclipse-luna-dark-theme) as well.

Comment: Also, if it is a known and fixed bug, what should I do to get the fix?